# how to position the cursor on the screen?

Tags: c, ide, codeblocks, cursor-position

I'm new in programming and currently learning about arrays in C. I'm making a puzzle that contains 15 numbered square pieces mounted on a frame and one piece is empty.It allow the user to hit any of the arrow keys(up,down,left,right).The user will continue hitting the arrow keys till the numbers aren't arranged in ascending order.These pieces can be move horizontally and vertically.
My problem is that i don't know how to position the cursor.I know a library function **gotoxy()** but i think it was used in Turbo C/C++.I'm using Code Blocks.I searched this on Google but couldn't get the result.And yes i'm talking about the keyboard cursor and using window OS.Please help! :)

Comment: Do you mean the mouse cursor ? What cursor are you talking about ?

Comment: @jean-loup I think OP is referring to the console cursor. BTW this depends on what platform you're using (i.e. Windows or Unix/Linux)

Comment: How this needs to be done depends on the type of terminal device the program will run in.  To support most terminals is an enormous job, and there are complet libraries like ncurses with decades of refinement for doing it.  That said, most common terminal devices support VT220/ANSI escape sequences for moving the cursor - you could search for them and they'll probably suffice.  See e.g. [here](http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ansi_esc.htm)

Answer (score 2):

In the old days, MS/DOS used a special driver ANSI.SYS to emulate ANSI command codes. It looks like this good old driver is usable under Windows XP (but you need do configure it in config.sys), but I found some articles saying it no longer works on Windows 7 and above.

So ANSI (or vt100 or vt220) codes are useful in Linux or Unix terminals, but under Windows, my advice would be to directly use the Windows API Console functions declared in Wincon.h - but you should alway include Windows.h when using Windows API functions.

You will need to use the Windows SDK as a reference, but here is a small program writing `foo_bar` in position 15,5 :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h> // compatibility 8/16 bits characters

int _tmain(int argc, const LPSTR *argv) {
    HANDLE hStdOut = ::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); // console output handle
    COORD dwCursorPosition;
    DWORD nb;
    dwCursorPosition.X = 15;
    dwCursorPosition.Y = 5;
    ::WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdOut, _T("foo_bar"), 7, dwCursorPosition, &nb);

    return 0;
}
```

References : [Console Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682087%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: it showing error after compiling "window.h : No such file or directory"

Comment: I wrote `windows.h` - note the `s`

Comment: oh..awesome it's working.Thankyou alot.Btw i'm learnind C so i can't understand whatever program you have written above.Can you please explain me it in C .It will be really helpful for me.

Comment: As you want to use low level IO functions, the problem is not the C language, but more the Windows API. `_tmain` is the progam entry point (analog to standard `main`) for Microsoft for compatibility 8/16 bits characters (declared in tchar.h). `HANDLE` is an opaque type, `DWORD` is an unsigned 32 bits integer, `COORD` is a typedef to a struct. `COORD`, `GetStdHandle` and `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter` are all described in the link given at the end of my post.

Comment: Well thanks for the reply.I want to clearly learn about this topic.Can you suggest me any book or any link.And one more thing in which part of programming this topic comes? I also want to understand the low level IO Function and about what is window API etc. :)

Comment: If you want to do use Windows API, you need the Windows SDK (just google for it). And I'm sorry I have nothing to recommend you except as usual googling for `windows API tutorial`. But IMHO, learn C first with simple programs not using API functions, and when you will be comfortable with that learn Windows API

Comment: Thankyou for your advice.Btw i asked the question because it was on my text book and i have to it anyway as i do each and every question.It' like a mini project for me! ;) :)